# How to add white space and extra axis labels to ggplot figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a geom_point figure with each 'var' group along the x axis.

As you can see in my data, the 'vars' fall into 3 broader groupings: Strength, Race/Ethnicity, and City.

So what I am trying to do is add a little white space in the figure between each of those groupings, and also add an additional x axis label for each of them (besides Total). For example, centered beneath the race/ethnicity categories would be an additional label that says "Race" or something along those lines. Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Code here

```
order1 <- c("Total", "Weak", "Strong", "White", "Black", "Hispanic", "Springfield", "Buxton", "Artowne", "Friedsville", "Alexandria", "Oldmill")

data %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(y = mean, x = var, color = var)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = order1) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Example data here

```
structure(list(category = c("points", "points", "points", "points", 
"points", "points", "points", "points", "points", "points", "points", 
"points"), var = c("Total", "Weak", "Strong", "White", "Black", 
"Hispanic", "Springfield", "Buxton", "Artowne", "Friedsville", 
"Alexandria", "Oldmill"), mean = c(175, 145, 160, 120, 200, 200, 
225, 200, 100, 160, 120, 100), lower = c(156, 120, 140, 100, 
168, 141, 191, 72, 45, 130, 100, 40), upper = c(190, 176, 185, 
150, 245, 240, 280, 340, 230, 200, 150, 150)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use faceting, i.e. add a column with the categories, then facet by that column. As the categories have different number of items I opted for `facet_grid` with `space = "free_x"` and `scales = "free_x"`, placed the strip labels at the bottom and used theme options to place the stripe text on the outside of the axis and to get rid of the outline.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

data |>
  mutate(
    var = factor(var, order1),
    category = case_match(
      var,
      c("Weak", "Strong") ~ "Strength",
      c("White", "Black", "Hispanic") ~ "Race",
      c(
        "Springfield", "Buxton", "Artowne",
        "Friedsville", "Alexandria", "Oldmill"
      ) ~ "City",
      .default = ""
    ),
    category = factor(category, c("", "Strength", "Race", "City"))
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(y = mean, x = var, color = var)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ category,
    space = "free_x", scales = "free_x",
    switch = "x"
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background.x = element_rect(color = NA)
  )
```

[image]

**UPDATE** You could use a labelling function using e.g. `dplyr::case_mtach` to assign different labels to the x axis categories which can be passed to the `labels=` argument of `scale_x_discrete` like so:

```r
labels_x <- function(x) {
  case_match(
    x,
    "Friedsville" ~  "Frieds\nVille",
    "Springfield" ~  "Spring-\nfield",
    .default = x
  )
}

data |>
  mutate(
    var = factor(var, order1),
    category = case_match(
      var,
      c("Weak", "Strong") ~ "Strength",
      c("White", "Black", "Hispanic") ~ "Race",
      c(
        "Springfield", "Buxton", "Artowne",
        "Friedsville", "Alexandria", "Oldmill"
      ) ~ "City",
      .default = ""
    ),
    category = factor(category, c("", "Strength", "Race", "City"))
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(y = mean, x = var, color = var)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels_x) +
  facet_grid(. ~ category,
    space = "free_x", scales = "free_x",
    switch = "x"
  ) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.background.x = element_rect(color = NA)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to additionally control the labels of the x axis? Let's say "Friedsville" was really called "Frieds Ville" and I wanted to the "Ville" part to be below Frieds

Comment: See my update for an approach to achieve your desired result.